# How does the unittest library determine whether to run a decorated method?

Tags: python

Tested with Python 2.7.12 on Linux.

I am trying to write a simple function that decorates a `test_*` method in `unittest.TestCase`. I know that methods that do not begin with `test_` are not considered actual tests and are not invoked directly when the test is run. I then wondered what you happen if you took a `test_` method and applied a naive decorator to it that made no attempt to preserve the name. I was expecting my test to be ignored and to have to modify my decorator to make sure that the function has a name beginning with `test_`. I was very, very surprised when the test ran anyway.

Here's the directory layout of the example

```
.
|-- add.py
|-- print_args.py
|-- test_add.py
`-- test_add_decorated.py

0 directories, 4 files
```

`add.py` is the library we are testing. It adds two things.

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

`print_args.py` is a library containing a decorator that prints the args and kwargs of a function as a side effect. It is written as naively as possible and makes no attempt to preserve the name of the function.

```
def print_args(wrapped):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print [args, kwargs]
        return apply(wrapped, args, kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Here is `test_add.py` which imports `add.py` and tests that `4 + 5 = 9`. The `__repr__` method of `TestAdd` is not directly relevant to this example, but will be in the next one.

```
import unittest
import add


class TestAdd(unittest.TestCase):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a unittest.TestCase! Fear me!"

    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(add.add(4, 5), 9)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When we run `test_add.py`, we can see that one test ran and it passed.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Now we apply the decorator to the `test_add` method in `test_add_decorated.py`.

```
import unittest
import print_args
import add


class TestAdd(unittest.TestCase):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "I am a unittest.TestCase! Fear me!"

    @print_args.print_args
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(add.add(4, 5), 9)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Before I ran this, I was expecting to see no errors, but an indication that zero tests had run, since the `test_add` method's name should now be `wrapper`.

That is not what happened. The `print_args` decorator worked fine, we can see the args and kwargs in an array and an indication that one test ran successfully.

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
[(I am a unittest.TestCase! Fear me!,), {}]
```

So, my question is ... how did the `unittest` library figure out that it was supposed to run my decorated method?

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: @SimeonVisser 2.7.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapper function's `__name__` might be `wrapper`, but it's still `TestAdd.test_add`. As in, if you look at the `TestAdd` class's `__dict__`, you'll find the wrapper function bound to key `'test_add'`, and if you wanted to call the method, you would use the name `test_add`, not `wrapper`.

When `unittest` uses method names to determine whether a method is a test, it doesn't look at the `__name__`. It looks at what attribute name the method is associated with, and the decorator doesn't affect that.

Comment: For context, you can see that it calls `dir()` on the test class itself here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/unittest/loader.py#l140